# How to deploy angular app

Tags: angularjs, deployment

I just finished an angular app and would like to deploy it to a web server. I'm actually looking for a free solution for now. I'm using 
http-server to launch my app so I don't have any other setup such as grunt or yeoman. I thought I could upload the files to my apache server but it shows blank.

This is how my file directory look. index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="musicSearch">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular App</title>

 <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="assets/styles/style.less">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.1/less.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Styles -->


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
   <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="routes.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
<script src="services.js"></script>
<script src="directives.js"></script>
```

Comment: You certainly can deploy it simply by uploading files to Apache, so you've done something wrong. Unfortunately you haven't given enough information to say what but you've almost certainly got some error messages in your javascript console that will give you a clue.

Comment: I drag the index.html to the browser and seen these errors  Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module spotifySearch due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/nomod?p0=ngRoute

Comment: So follow the link you just posted: it you says you have a dependency on a module that you haven't loaded.

Comment: You'll likely need a build process (grunt, gulp, webpack, etc.) that can bundle together all of your javascript files into one. Then you'll need to move index.html, compiled javascript file (main.js or whatever it is named) and css into the same place on the server. Also, you'll need to use the build process to compile your less into css (browsers can't parse less/sass, only css).

Comment: I got it working now. I need to add https to the cdn. Thanks